# Which open source forges for bzr/bazaar?

Tags: dvcs, bazaar

I'm looking for an open source forge that we can host in our lab for some private projetcs. Our favorite DVCS is bzr so this forge must support bzr repositories.

While Launchpad is open source, this forge does not seem to be admin-friendly for hosting a private clone (no support, no migration script for database schema modifications, etc).

Are you aware of any good alternative ?

Thanks !

Edit:

We are now using git for our projects, and rhodecode to manage central repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new one: sloecode. It is still a rather young project. Several plugins are still missing, like a bug tracker and a wiki, but those features are planned.  It's worth looking at it for small private branches.

http://how-bazaar.blogspot.com/2011/03/announcing-sloecode.html

https://launchpad.net/sloecode

Answer (score 3):

You can use Redmine or Trac (required trac-bzr plugin) installations to host your private projects.

Answer (score 1):

Where I work they started to use [Gforge AS](http://gforge.com/gf/) a couple of years ago. Since I love Bazaar I made a [bzr plugin for gforge](http://gforge.com/gf/project/scmbzr/). It was not 100% complete but was functional enough to use - it is still in use where I work.

On looking this up for you, I saw [Fusion Forge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FusionForge) which might be easier to get going, [it is a fork of the free Gforge](https://fusionforge.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7) with [built in support for bazaar](http://roland.entierement.nu/blog/2009/07/fusionforge-news-july-2009.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Savannah](http://savannah.nongnu.org) uses many VC systems, including Bazaar.  I'm not sure what you mean by "admin-friendly" but it's been quite friendly to me.  I also have a project on Launchpad.

Comment: The Savannah "support" for bzr is the closest possible thing to inexistent: it only supports inefficient sftp and http access, no source code browsing, and presumably no sort of bug tracker or timeline integration.

Comment: Yes, I've experienced how they haven't really set it up yet.  I've also seen talk from the Emacs developers about how the Savannah hackers need to get it set up very soon ;)  Hopefully any improvements the Emacs developers can encourage will spill over to other Bazaar users.